# What locale argument to pass to NSDecimalNumber +decimalNumberWithString:locale: so it always works with NSString's using the dot (.) decimal mark?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, nsdecimalnumber, nslocale

I have an NSString which I want to convert into an `NSDecimalNumber`. The string is received from a server and is always formatted using the `en_US` locale like `XXX.YYY` and not like `XXX,YYY`. I want to create an `NSDecimalNumber` which accepts `XXX.YYY` regardless of the locale the user. The number is never displayed to the user, it's used to do internal math.

Normally you'd do something like this:

```
NSDecimalNumber *n = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.234"];
```

However, if the user is running the `fr_FR` locale of Mac OS X, that will break. `en_US` will interpret it as *one point two three four*, where-as `fr_FR` will interpret it as *one-thousand two-hundred thirty-four*, both very different numbers.

The obvious solution is to use `+decimalNumberWithString:locale:`. But I'm not sure what to pass as an argument to the `locale:` parameter which will work on all international versions of Mac OS X. My best guess is to do this:

```
NSLocale        *l = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
NSDecimalNumber *n = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.234" locale:l];
```

Is that the best way to do this, and is it safe? Will the `@"en_US"` local identifier be available on all international versions of Mac OS X, or might it return a `nil` NSLocale in some cases?

---

**UPDATE 1:** This appears to work well, and is more explicit:

```
NSDictionary    *l = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"." forKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
NSDecimalNumber *n = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.234" locale:l];
```

`NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` is a constant defined for NSLocale, which responds to `-objectWithKey:`, just like NSDictionary. You can feed it any decimal mark separator you want, like `@","`.

I think this is likely the best answer to the question, unless anyone else has a better idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to work well, and is more explicit:

```
NSDictionary    *l = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"." forKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
NSDecimalNumber *n = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.234" locale:l];
```

`NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` is a constant defined for NSLocale, which responds to `-objectWithKey:`, just like NSDictionary. You can feed it any decimal mark separator you want, like `@","`.

I think this is likely the best answer to the question, unless anyone else has a better idea?