# NSDecimalNumber rounding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would to round a decimal number like this :

4363,65 ----> 4364

I have tried this :

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString@"4363,65"];

NSDecimalNumberHandler  *behav = [[NSDecimalNumberHandler alloc] initWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:NSDecimalNoScale
                                                raiseOnExactness:YES
                                                 raiseOnOverflow:YES
                                                raiseOnUnderflow:YES
                                             raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];

NSDecimalNumber *roundedDecimal = [decimalNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:behav];
```

I don't have the expected result.How i can round it ?

Comment: what is your result?

Comment: What is your locale? You are using `,` as a decimal separator. Is the original `decimalNumber` parsed correctly?

Comment: the result is : 4363

Comment: Either force usage of a [proper separator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7905775/792677) or change your protocol to reliable parse the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems in your code. The first is the creation of the number. You are using `,` as a decimal separator. If your locale is not configured to use `,` for decimals, your number will be parsed as `4363`. This is what probably happens.

The second problem is the value for the `scale` parameter. It takes the number of decimal digits but you are using a constant `NSDecimalNoScale` which is actually equal to `SHRT_MAX`. That's not what you want.

```
//make sure you use the correct format depending on your locale
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4363.65"]; 

NSDecimalNumberHandler  *behav = [[NSDecimalNumberHandler alloc] initWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain
                                                       scale:0
                                            raiseOnExactness:YES
                                             raiseOnOverflow:YES
                                            raiseOnUnderflow:YES
                                         raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My error was with the locale and the scale as you said

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way:
float f = 4363,65;
int rounded = (f + 0.5);

Comment: i want  to do it witch decimalNumber